# create website in visual studio

Tags: jquery, html, css, visual-studio-2012, web

The question is can I create a website in Visual Studio 2012? By which I mean like you can in Adobe Dreamweaver? I don't want to create an asp.net project, just a standard website with HTML, JS and JQuery. I want to use VS because I like the intellisense, the ability to organise project files in the solution explorer and have everything easily accessible. At the moment I am just loading the index.html or stylesheet.css in to edit them but I would like if it i could browse through it as if it was a project.

I know Dreamweaver can do this, the reason why I am asking is because I don't have any licences for Dreamweaver so it would be more practical if I could do it in VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a folder with all your HTML and CSS files and so on in it, you can open it by File > Open > Website.
 You can browse to your desired folder or ftp server. When you opened your desired folder you have everything in your solution explorer. 
To make a .sln file of this now just browse to File > Save YourFolderName.sln As...
Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create static HTML web sites in Visual Studio, however I don't know that a project template exists for this.

That being said, you could just create an empty ASP.NET application, but use HTML/CSS/JavaScript, without using any ASPX pages, or code. I've successfully achieved this for several static webpages / HTML tests etc.

TypeScript also provides a similar template for static HTML based web sites, however, I believe that this template is also based on an empty ASP.NET application, but modified for TypeScript development (it inclused an app.ts file, which you can delete if it's not necessary).